# Best way to develop a simple video chat app for android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, video, chat

I am trying to develop a simple Video Chat app, but I don't know how to Start.

I know there are a couple of ways to do this: `WebRTC, Adobe Flex.`

But WebRTC is only for p2p and the Adobe Products are expensive.

Do you know better ways to develop a Video Chat? The best would be a small tutorial.

Comment: A "small" tutorial on writing a video chat application is an oxymoron.

Comment: Small tutorial on video chat application: iOS: http://docs.frozenmountain.com/icelink2/index.html#class=icelink-getting-started-creating-a-conference-10_ios-macosx, Android: http://docs.frozenmountain.com/icelink2/index.html#class=icelink-getting-started-creating-a-conference-20_java :-D

Comment: The upvotes on this seem very suspect!

Answer (score 2):

I'm a developer with the easyRTC project. It is WebRTC based (thus no IOS), but it's also easy for most people with a little JavaScript experience to get working.

- [Opensource Homepage](https://github.com/priologic/easyrtc)
- [Live Demo site](http://demo.easyrtc.com/)
- [Support forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/easyrtc)
- [Video of Windows 7 install](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FcQU2_OTsaQ)
- [Video of cross-platform install](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nq042zJ_em4)

Currently it's still early-days, so OS and browser support is currently limited. WebRTC is supported by Chrome and Firefox beta on Windows, Linux, Android.

Comment: Thank you for the WebRTC example, but i am working now on an AIR solutiuon, because i want it as an app and not in the browser.

Comment: is it possible to select front or back camera on phones ..??

Comment: I looked at the links and its seems like this for Desktops only. How can this be used for android?