# is adobe air replaces flex on mobile browsers?

Tags: apache-flex, air

we have developed video confernce using flex builder 4.6 which works perfectly on desktop browsers. we just added the video box from flex in the browser and everything else is plain html and javascript code. when we open our site on any tablet or latwst mobiles the flex component is unable to connect to wowza server. I want to know what additionally I have to do for flex component to work on tablet browsers without doing lot of changes in code such as not using transcoders to convert live video and audio to one of those html5 supported format.

Answer (score 1):

Your subject line does not seem to relate to your actual question; but I'll try to address your points.

> is adobe air replaces flex on mobile browsers?

Adobe AIR is a way to build native applications for iOS, Android, and Blackberry devices.  It is not a tool for delivering Flash content through a browser.

Adobe did create a mobile browser plugin for Flash.  That is available on Blackberry devices; and was available for Android devices.  On Android it is no longer being updated or maintained.

> when we open our site on any tablet or latwst mobiles the flex
>   component is unable to connect to wowza server.

What is the error you receive?

> I want to know what additionally I have to do for flex component to
>   work on tablet browsers

On iOS, or Windows Phone, there is nothing you can do.

On most Android devices, you'll have [to manually install the Adobe Flash Player](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/1061194).

On current Blackberry devices, it should just work.

Comment: can you suggest me how to make the video conference to work on android or ios browsers?

Comment: No; I can't.  You won't be able to use Flash Player.  Try a Google search.  Here is one link that came up: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17010212/best-way-to-develop-a-simple-video-chat-app-for-android-and-ios